# How can I connect to a apache derby database using python?

Tags: python, database, derby

This is my class for connecting to derby. I am attempting to make a connection to and Embedded apache derby database
the derby database is in a folder I named Config. this is not a database that is running on a server and a specific port - it is an embedded database.

```
    """ 
    This class handles connecting to the database and contains methods 
    allowing retrieval of report data base on parameters such as 
    error_type, date, and dropboxtype
    """
    import drda as db
    import jaydebeapi as derby
    import sqlite3 as sl 
    import traceback
    
    class sqlservice:
    
        def __init__(self,driver,url):
            self.driver = driver
            self.url = url
    
    
        def connect(self):
            ok = None
            try:
                db.connect
                con = derby.connect(self.driver,self.url)
                ok = con
                
            except ConnectionError:
                print("Connection failed: ")
                traceback.print_exc()
                
        def get_success_status():
            """ 
            Runs a query returning a list of success status based on a filter
            filter can be date, dropboxtype, or error_type
            """
        def get_quarantine_status():
            """ 
            Runs a query returning a list of quarantine status based on a filter
            filter can be date, dropboxtype, or error_type
            """
        def get_error_type():
    
            return None
            
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        launchservice = sqlservice("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver","jdbc:derby:Config")
        launchservice.connect()
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Do you get any errors? How does the behaviour differ from what you expect?

Comment: I get TypeError: Class org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver is not found

Comment: That means that the underlying Java class doesn't get found. How are you configuring your CLASSPATH? Another option is to give the path to the jar file as an argument to connect if you aren't able to set it up properly. See https://pypi.org/project/JayDeBeApi/#usage for an exmaple